# On identifying a base for a topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $x=\{a,b,c\}$, $A=\{a,b\}$, $B=\{b,c\}$, and let
> $\mathscr{G}=\big\{\emptyset, X, A, B\big\}$. Is $\mathscr{G}$ a base
> for a topology in $X$?

**Definition:**
A family $\mathscr{G}$ of open subsets of a topological space $T$ is called a base for $T$ if every open set in $T$ can be represented as a union of sets in $\mathscr{G}$

*My take:*

Clearly $A$ and $B$ cannot be represented as a union of sets in $\mathscr{G}$, since they have a non-empty intersection. Hence a base would have been $\mathscr{G}_2=\{\emptyset, X, \{a\}, \{a,b\}\big\}$ instead than $\mathscr{G}=\big\{\emptyset, X, A, B\big\}$.

However, isn't the empty intersection-requirement a particular property of Hausdorff space, and not for any topology? Basically, I am not sure my formulation is exactly correct.

any ideas appreciated.

Comment: $A\cap B=\{b\}$ so there would need to be some basis set contained in the intersection which also contained $b$, but there isn't.  Your second example fails because $c$ isn't in the union.

Comment: @lulu But c is in X in the second example

Comment: @Tim  Ah, you are right. Read that as $\emptyset$ for some reason.

Comment: I think you can check the definition of base from the Munkre's book,which says
(1) $\forall x\in X, \exists B, \text{ s.t. } x\in B$ and
(2) $\forall x\in B_1\cap B_2,  \exists B\subset B_1\cap B_2 \text{ s.t. } x\in B$

Comment: Also, different basis elements $A,B$ may have non-empty intersection, as lulu said,  your base should contain some basis set contained in the intersection.

Comment: the question is really if that given family is a base. My argument, with correction is that it isnt.. Thanks Lulu for that clarification

Comment: "Clearly $A$ and $B$ cannot be represented as a union of sets in $\scr G$." - Since they are both in $\scr G$ themselves, they clearly *can* represented as such a union: $A = \bigcup_{X \in \{A\}} X$. The sole failure here is that since $A$ and $B$ are open, so $A\cap B$ is also open, but it is $A\cap B = \{b\}$ that cannot be expressed as a union of the elements of $\scr G$.